# How to stop Twitter from switching to mobile site

Tags: twitter, mobile

The last few times I have gone to [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com) it has automatically switched to the [mobile site](http://mobile.twitter.com). How can I keep it on the standard site?

Chromium 48.0.2564.82 (Developer Build)
Ubuntu 15.10 (32-bit)

Comment: Have you checked you browser’s user agent setting?